# Parse "orderByDescending" query

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I've two classes called `Followers` and `Posts` , I am trying to make the home screen by which i will be able to see the posts by the users i am following, and my posts too.. so i tried this to get the query of posts :

```
func loadData() {

    var postQuery:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
    postQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    postQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

        if let objects = objects {

            for object in objects {

                self.data.addObject(object)
                println(object.createdAt)
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }

        }


    }

}
```

here `postQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt")` is working fine.. `println(object.createdAt)` gives perfect result :

```
  Optional(2015-08-25 22:31:12 +0000)
  Optional(2015-08-25 22:28:28 +0000)
  Optional(2015-08-25 22:25:36 +0000)
  Optional(2015-08-24 13:40:48 +0000)
  Optional(2015-08-24 13:39:25 +0000)
```

and if i try to query followed users too , like this :

```
  func loadData() {

    let postsByCurrentUser = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
        postsByCurrentUser.orderByAscending("createdAt")
        postsByCurrentUser.whereKey("postedBy", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    postsByCurrentUser.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({ (objects, error) -> Void in

        if let posts = objects as? [PFObject] {

            for post in posts {


            }

        }


    })

    var posts:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Followers")
        posts.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
        posts.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

            if let objects = objects {

                for object in objects {

                    var followedId = object["user"] as! PFObject

                    var postsByFollowedUser:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
                        postsByFollowedUser.whereKey("postedBy", equalTo: followedId)
                    postsByFollowedUser.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

                        if let objects = objects {

                            for object in objects {

                            }

                        }

                    })

                }

            }

    }
}
```

using this code i'm getting a random order of the posts.
where am i wrong here.. if you need any explanation about the question i can give you but help me out here.. i m not able to find the error. so basically :

1. I want to get the posts in orderByDescending according to the time.
2. Here i am getting the posts by the users which are being followed by the current user but the current user's posts. What should i do for that ?

Comment: Are you trying to query the post of your followers using their latest time ?

Comment: post of users i follow and my posts too.. yes,latest time.

Comment: When you query do you get all posts or it's just the time that is messing up

Comment: yes i get all the posts. but not in the order i am trying. and using this code gives me the posts posted by the users i follow but not mine, because i'vent defined it anywhere in the code. i don't know where should i do that :/

Comment: So in the follower class you have your post and the followers posts also right

Comment: okay.. let me explain it .. "Followers" class have columns called "follower" and "user" (the user being followed by follower) and the other class is "Posts" which have the column "postedBy"(objectId of the user who has posted the post) .. so i am querying from the class "Followers" first to get the users and then matching it to the "postedBy" column to get the posts of already followed users.. hope that explains. and yeah "Posts" class have the posts by the followed users and mine too

Comment: Like I think you are doing too much work... if i understand what you just explain. Your best bet is to have one Class POSTByFollower where you have you have the follower details and the currentUser details

Comment: the answer i post was if you were query from the same class

Comment: @AkshayKheveria you can not query two separate classes within the same query. Thats what relations/pointers are for.

Comment: then what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

First off, I am an Android Developer and do not do iOS but I think I get what you are trying to do, so please translate it accordingly. You would want to look at ParseQuery.whereMatchesQuery(). Basically you will have 2 queries: one is for the posts which is the main query and another one for the followers.

```
// Query to find followers of current user
ParseQuery<ParseObject> queryFollowers = ParseQuery.getQuery("Followers");
queryFollowers.whereMatches("follower", currentUser.getId());

// Query to find posts 
ParseQuery<ParseObject> postQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Posts");    
// Retrieves posts which statisfies the first query (followers of current user)
postQuery.whereMatchesQuery("postedBy", queryFollowers);
postQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt");

// Objects returned here are the posts by followers
postQuery.findInBackground...
```

Comment: getting this error : 'Cannot do a comparison query for type: PFQuery'

Comment: using this query i am getting this error : [Error]: bad type for $inQuery

Comment: @AkshayKheveria Change `postQuery.whereKey("postedBy", equalTo: followersQuery)` with whereKey:matchesQuery:

Comment: yeah i've done it..but still getting the error: [Error]: bad type for $inQuery

Answer (score 0):

So here is complete answer ..

I know it isn't the most optimal code ( u can refactor it into methods ) but it gives u wanted result ...

```
--- Sorted posts by current user
Optional(Test)
Optional(Test1)
Optional(Test2)
Optional(Test3)
Optional(Test4)
Optional(Test20)

--- Sorted posts by every follower 

Optional(Test10)
Optional(Test11)
Optional(Test12)
```

Complete code is here:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
            PFUser.logOut()
        }

        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground("test", password: "test") { (let currentUser, let error) -> Void in

            println("---")
              // Insert test post

//            let testPost = PFObject(className: "Posts")
//            testPost["post"] = "Test20"
//            let userRelation : PFRelation = testPost.relationForKey("postedBy")
//            userRelation.addObject(PFUser.currentUser()!)
//            testPost.saveEventually()

              // Insert test relation

//            let userToFollow = PFUser.query()
//            userToFollow?.whereKey("username", equalTo: "test1")
//            userToFollow?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (let result, let error) -> Void in
//                
//                if let follower = result!.first! as? PFUser {
//                    
//                    let followers = PFObject(className: "Followers")
//                    let userRelation : PFRelation = followers.relationForKey("user")
//                    userRelation.addObject(PFUser.currentUser()!)
//                    let followerRelation : PFRelation = followers.relationForKey("follower")
//                    followerRelation.addObject(follower)
//                    
//                    followers.saveEventually()
//                }
//            })

            // Get posts by currentUser

            let postsByCurrentUser = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
            postsByCurrentUser.orderByAscending("createdAt")
            postsByCurrentUser.whereKey("postedBy", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
            postsByCurrentUser.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (let pfPosts, let error) -> Void in

                if let posts = pfPosts as? [PFObject] {

                    for post in posts {
                        println(post["post"])
                    }

                }

            })

            // Get posts by followers

            let postsByCurrentUserFollowers = PFQuery(className: "Followers")
            postsByCurrentUserFollowers.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
            postsByCurrentUserFollowers.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (let pfFollowers, let error) -> Void in


                if let followers = pfFollowers as? [PFObject] {

                    for follower in followers {

                        let userFollowerRelation = follower.relationForKey("follower")
                        userFollowerRelation.query()!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (let followerToUser, let error) -> Void in

                            if let followerUser = followerToUser!.first! as? PFUser {

                                let postsByCurrentUser = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
                                postsByCurrentUser.orderByAscending("createdAt")
                                postsByCurrentUser.whereKey("postedBy", equalTo: followerUser)
                                postsByCurrentUser.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (let pfPosts, let error) -> Void in

                                    if let posts = pfPosts as? [PFObject] {

                                        for post in posts {
                                            println(post["post"])
                                        }

                                    }

                                })


                            }

                        })



                    }
                }
            })

        }

    }
```

Comment: thanks man.. how can i remove the follower?? like if i unfollow a user.

Comment: delete row with self.follower.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row) for example

Comment: this is just giving me current user's posts nothing else. :/

Comment: i put Relations instead of pointers in db ... so u must have follower and user as a pointers and postedby must be pointer

Comment: i tried it.. see my updated code in the question. how should i add the data to `data` `NSMutableArray` ?? and where would be the `tableView.reloadData()` ??