# whereKey:matchesQuery: is not giving any result

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, parse-platform

I've two classes called `Followers` and `Posts` . something like this:

`Follower =(user , follower)` , both user and follower contains `Pointers`.

`Posts = (post, postedBy)`, here postedBy contains `Pointers`. i want to retrieve the posts `posted` by the current user itself and the posts postedBy the users being followed by the current user. i am trying this:

```
func loadData() {

    var queryFollowers:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Followers")
        queryFollowers.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    var postQuery:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
        postQuery.whereKey("postedBy", matchesQuery: queryFollowers)

    var postQueryCurrentUser:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
        postQueryCurrentUser.whereKey("postedBy", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    var compoundQuery = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([postQuery, postQueryCurrentUser])
        compoundQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

            if let objects = objects {

                for object in objects {

                    self.data.addObject(object)
                    println(self.data)

                }

            }

    }
}
```

so what should i do to achieve it? Thanks for your time..

Answer (score 0):

So here is complete answer ..

I know it isn't the most optimal code ( u can refactor it into methods ) but it gives u wanted result ...

```
--- Sorted posts by current user
Optional(Test)
Optional(Test1)
Optional(Test2)
Optional(Test3)
Optional(Test4)
Optional(Test20)

--- Sorted posts by every follower 

Optional(Test10)
Optional(Test11)
Optional(Test12)
```

Complete code is here:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
            PFUser.logOut()
        }

        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground("test", password: "test") { (let currentUser, let error) -> Void in

            println("---")
              // Insert test post

//            let testPost = PFObject(className: "Posts")
//            testPost["post"] = "Test20"
//            let userRelation : PFRelation = testPost.relationForKey("postedBy")
//            userRelation.addObject(PFUser.currentUser()!)
//            testPost.saveEventually()

              // Insert test relation

//            let userToFollow = PFUser.query()
//            userToFollow?.whereKey("username", equalTo: "test1")
//            userToFollow?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (let result, let error) -> Void in
//                
//                if let follower = result!.first! as? PFUser {
//                    
//                    let followers = PFObject(className: "Followers")
//                    let userRelation : PFRelation = followers.relationForKey("user")
//                    userRelation.addObject(PFUser.currentUser()!)
//                    let followerRelation : PFRelation = followers.relationForKey("follower")
//                    followerRelation.addObject(follower)
//                    
//                    followers.saveEventually()
//                }
//            })

            // Get posts by currentUser

            let postsByCurrentUser = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
            postsByCurrentUser.orderByAscending("createdAt")
            postsByCurrentUser.whereKey("postedBy", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
            postsByCurrentUser.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (let pfPosts, let error) -> Void in

                if let posts = pfPosts as? [PFObject] {

                    for post in posts {
                        println(post["post"])
                    }

                }

            })

            // Get posts by followers

            let postsByCurrentUserFollowers = PFQuery(className: "Followers")
            postsByCurrentUserFollowers.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
            postsByCurrentUserFollowers.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (let pfFollowers, let error) -> Void in


                if let followers = pfFollowers as? [PFObject] {

                    for follower in followers {

                        let userFollowerRelation = follower.relationForKey("follower")
                        userFollowerRelation.query()!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (let followerToUser, let error) -> Void in

                            if let followerUser = followerToUser!.first! as? PFUser {

                                let postsByCurrentUser = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
                                postsByCurrentUser.orderByAscending("createdAt")
                                postsByCurrentUser.whereKey("postedBy", equalTo: followerUser)
                                postsByCurrentUser.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (let pfPosts, let error) -> Void in

                                    if let posts = pfPosts as? [PFObject] {

                                        for post in posts {
                                            println(post["post"])
                                        }

                                    }

                                })


                            }

                        })



                    }
                }
            })

        }

    }
```

Comment: like what? sorry, beginner here.

Comment: i edited my post .. U didnt run search for first query anywhere so it didnt give u any results ... u have to have search in search like i posted in edited post

Comment: no i've a problem there .. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32250956/parse-orderbydescending-query

Comment: ill try to simulate the problem

Answer (score 0):

it is me again. Again I am not an iOS Developer, I do Android but I am familiar with the Parse APIs. You should be reading the Parse iOS Developer Guide about compund queries.

Create an additional 2 queries so total will be four:

1. Find all followers (queryFollowers)
2. Find all posts by followers (postQuery)
3. Find all posts by current user *NEW*
4. Combine the queries 2 and 3 by compound queries *NEW*

   func loadData() {

   ```
   var queryFollowers:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Followers")
       queryFollowers.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
   var postQuery:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
       postQuery.whereKey("postedBy", matchesQuery: queryFollowers)
   var postQueryCurrentUser:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
       postQueryCurrentUser.whereKey("postedBy", equalTo:PFUser.currentUser())
   PFQuery *compoundQuery = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[postQuery,postQueryCurrentUser]];
   ```

   `[compoundQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
     // results contains posts from current user and followers
   }];`

I am not sure about the syntax. But I hope you get the idea. And also please consider accepting my answer to your yesterday's question. =)

Comment: this is giving me just the current user's posts :/